# Freeing the memory in a quad tree project

Tags: c

I have a program that creates a quad tree using malloc. I then have a function that then removes the tree by freeing all nodes.

On a level one tree I free all 5 allocs, however on a level 2 I only free 17 of 21 allocs an I'm having trouble seeing where the problem is.

Any help in this would be very helpful, below is the removeTree function:

```
void removeTree(Node *node)
 {
  int i = 0;

     if( node->child[0] == NULL )
        free(node);
    else {
      for ( i=0; i<4; ++i ) {
        removeTree( node->child[i]);
         }
       }

    return;
  }
```

Comment: `if( node->child[0] == NULL ) free(node);` is not executed if first child is not NULL.

Comment: a description of the Node structure would be usefull. what does it mean for child pointer to be NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where you have children, you'll leak the current node. The algorithm should look something like this:

```
void removeTree(Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) 
        return;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        removeTree(node->child[i]);
        node->child[i] = NULL;
    }

    free(node);
}
```

Comment: `node->child[i] = NULL;` is actually unnecessary.